# Mongodb update. setOnInsert Mod on _id not allowed

Tags: mongodb

I understand the fact that you can't update _id on an existing mongodb document.

But is there a reason that we can't use it in an upsert in the 'setOnInsert' part ? Because it is 'on insert' so it's not an update.

My expected usage is this:

```
db.myCol.update({_id:12345},{$setOnInsert:{_id:12345},$set:{myValue:'hi'}});
```

Is this a bug or am i missing something ?

Comment: where is the upsert flag? just leave setOnInsert off and the right thing will happen.  db.myCol.update({_id:12345},{$set:{myValue:'hi'}})

Comment: Yeah you're right i forgot to include the upsert flag.
Apparently it automatically includes the find part to the insert if it's an upsert. Thanks :)

Comment: exactly. do you want to write it up as the answer or should I?

Answer (score 11):

MongoDB uses the 'query' part for an upsert query as part of the set, meaning that you don't have to specify the _id in the set part of you want to specify your own _id.

note: my query above also had a small bug which was the missing upsert flag.

This is the correct query:

```
db.myCol.update({_id:12345},{$set:{myValue:'hi'}},{upsert:true});
```

If the record doesn't exist, this query will insert a record which looks like this:

```
{_id:12345,myValue:'hi'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Really, this is a bug in mongo fixed in development version 2.5.4 or release 2.6.0:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9958

Once that's fixed, I believe this should work as desired.  In the general case, the query for update won't necessarily specify an "_id" field.

Comment: If this is a bug, it is still present in 3.4. I've tried to use $setOnInsert with the {_id}, but it threw the Mod on _id not allowed at me.